# Derive logitboost using the logistic loss function

Tags: machine-learning, convex-optimization

An additive model constructed using the exponential loss function

$$L(y, f (x)) = \exp(−yf (x))$$

gives   Adaboost. How can we derive the corresponding additive model (known as logitboost) using the logistic loss function

$$L(y, f (x)) = \log(1 + \exp(−yf (x)))$$

What steps I should take to do the above proof?

Comment: I suggest modifying this to ask a concrete theoretical question -- e.g. "How does one minimize logistic loss...".

Answer (score 2):

Originally, Logitboost was derived by Friedman, Hastie, and Tibshirani ([paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.51.9525)) -- their algorithm internally used a numerical procedure, via Newtons method to solve a regression problem.

Later, Collins, Schapire, and Singer ([paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.9.329)) found an equivalent formulation, with a single-line modification from AdaBoost, setting 
$$D(i) \propto \frac{1}{1+e^{y_i f_{t-1}(x_i)}}.$$

Schapire has a nice summary of boosting [here](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~mkearns/teaching/COLT/schapire.pdf), which also discusses Logitboost.

Comment: looks like I didn't ask the question clearly, I have cleaned up. I understand the adaboost.

Answer (score 2):

To get you answer,you may wanna look at this paper  http://dept.stat.lsa.umich.edu/~gmichail/ada_final.pdf.
Algorithm 2 summarizes the step you have to take to derive a boosting algorithm from any given convex loss including logitboost.